# Reactjs Material-UI - Unexpected token on arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, material-ui, arrow-functions

I'm attempting to incorporate [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) components into a project built off of [react-rocket-boilerplate](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/react-rocket-boilerplate).

I'm getting this error:

> [23:55:11] gulp-notify: [Compile Error] C:/react-rocket-boilerplate/app/js/components/Sidebar.js: Unexpected token (13:15) while parsing file: C:\react-rocket-boilerplate\app\js\components\Sidebar.js

*NOTE: Sidebar.js is an exact copy of the first leftNav example ("SIMPLE CONTROLLED LEFTNAV") provided on the material-ui documentation site with just the component name changed.*

Here is Sidebar.js:

```
import React            from 'react';
import LeftNav          from 'material-ui/lib/left-nav';
import MenuItem         from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';
import RaisedButton     from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button';

export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          label="Simple Controlled LeftNav"
          onTouchTap={this.handleToggle} />
        <LeftNav open={this.state.open}>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
        </LeftNav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the line in question:

```
  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
```

The character at (13:15) is the space immediately following "handleToggle".

I can use this syntax instead:

```
handleToggle() {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
}
```

... which resolves the error, but doesn't allow me access to "this" when it gets called.

Arrow functions DO compile when used in this context:

```
import React from 'react';

const Logo = () => (
  <div className="logo">
    Hello World
  </div>
);

export default Logo;
```

I'm more than happy to provide any and all additional info that might help, just let me know.

Also... is there a term for these different syntaxes/formats for component definition?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I have solved it with installing babel-preset-stage-1, and adding it to the .babelrc file.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-1
```

.babelrc

```
"presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have changed the arrow functions to plain old functions, you should use "bind" while assigning event handlers, like so -

```
onTouchTap={this.handleToggle.bind(this)}
```

Onto the syntax, its ES6 class, using Arrow functions to declare pre-bound methods, I haven't used gulp personally, but the source link you mentioned seems to be using babel with ES6 support, the code should have compiled :|. Wait for an answer from someone who knows about that.

Comment: Your suggestion definitely works! At least I can continue what I'm working on for now. Thank you very much for that.

Like you said though, I don't know why it isn't compiling with the arrow functions though... and it would be nice to resolve that. Hopefully someone has some insight there.

Comment: Good to know this helped you partially. You mention your code is based on the existing boiler plate, hope you also have a babelrc file with the right config. Please use your votes to indicate a helpful answer, thanks.

Comment: From babeljs [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#gulp), if you have babel 6 installed, it doesn't come with the presets, please check if you have the ES 2015 preset installed. You can install it using this commanded `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just started playing with react today and I had a similar issue. I managed to get this to work in my case by binding the function in question to `this` in the constructor. So in your case:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {open: false};
  // Make our bindings here
  this.handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  this.handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});
}
```

I don't really like this solution because it seems super hacky. I'll follow up if I figure out the "right" way to do this.